# The meaning of the badge "Sportsmanship"

Tags: discussion, support, badges

I would appreciate if you explain on the meaning of the badge "[Sportmanship](https://mathoverflow.net/help/badges/58/sportsmanship)".

It is described as below but I can not understand  what does it mean. May you describe  this badge in an equivalent words?

"Up vote 100 answers on questions of yours has a positive score"

Does it mean that  the winner has asked 100 different questions each question  receive at least one +1 and each  one has at least one answer with at least one +1?

Furthermore why this badge is called "Sportsman"?

Comment: You've left out a bit – it's actually "Up vote 100 answers on questions where an answer of yours has a positive score." It has nothing to do with asking questions, only with answering them, and voting up answers other people have posted to questions you have also answered.

Comment: @Gerry Thank you. Now I understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's quite simple. Just look at answering questions as a kind of "competition" between answerers. If the same question has several answers, the answerers are competing with each other, and the answer with most upvotes is on top. (Well, usually - it depends on how user chooses to sort the answers, but this seems to be the most frequently used setting.)

So if your main objective would be to maximize reputation, it's better for you to have your answer among the higher voted answers near to the top - since it is more visible. But if other answers are good, it is nice of you to upvote them - even if this means that your answer might gets ranked lower and thus less visible. So in this way your behavior is "sportsmanlike" - you help people who "compete" against you, in a sense.

(Whether or not looking at participation on MathOverflow and other Stack Exchange sites as a "competition" is more useful or more harmful is up for debate - probably it has both positive and negative aspects. I have mentioned this here mainly as an analogy to explain the choice of the name. Regardless of whether you consider [gamification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamification) useful or not, this badges rewards behavior which I would definitely consider as a positive contribution.)

> Does it mean that the winner has asked 100 different questions each question receive at least one +1 and each one has at least one answer with at least one +1?

No. It means the you need to have some answers (with positive score) and in each of those instances you have to upvote some competing answers. (And you need to cast at least 100 such upvotes in total.)

Users who do not have the badge can check progress towards it in the usual way - using the [badge tracker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/badge-progress/info) on their profile page.

The tag was introduced here: [Please add a new badge called “Good sport”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5145). If you are interested in more detailed information about this badge, probably looking at the posts tagged [sportsmanship-badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sportsmanship-badge) on Meta Stack Exchange might be a reasonable place.

Comment: Thank you Now I understand.

Comment: As I read the description, you don't need 100 answers yourself -- upvoting $n$ competing answers to the same question counts $n$ times towards the 100. -- Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @StefanKohl Thanks for the correction - I have edited the post. I have checked the following question to make sure that it is indeed as you write. [Are upvotes on competing posts counted per question or per answer for Sportsmanship?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105637) (Some of the [linked questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/105637) might be of interest, too.)

Comment: @Stefan, so that would mean all you have to do is answer a question that already has 100 answers, wait for someone to give it an upvote, and then upvote all those other answers.